# В чем может быть проблема, на хостинге изменился index.php

Tags: битрикс, index

Изменился индексный файл, в нем появилась строка вида: \x47L\x4fB\x41\x4cS"}["b\x5f\x6f\x68\x63y\x71\x73\x5f\x63p\x63\x6eb\x5f\x70g\x67x\x70
Что это могло быть?

Comment: Не знаю, что это, но там такой текст: `GLOBALS"}["b_ohcyqs_cpcnb_pggxp`

Comment: Сломали. Может майнят, может терминал сделали.

Comment: На вирус смахивает. Подстановка кода. Проверяйте все файлы сайта, если еще найдете подобное, то скорее всего. Если декодировать, то можно увидеть код, по которому ясно станет зараза это или ошибка работы отдельных методов при не правильно настроенном сервере.

Comment: Если вас взломали и взломали через вас же сайт, то скорее всего он имеет уязвимости. Если вы используете какой-то фреймворк, то ваши переменные окружения должны быть недоступны для просмотра из вне и режим приложения должен быть продакшен, чтобы не светить переменными во время ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

Firsov36 да, прав, вирус был, совсем недавно в разработке, не ожидал что такое может быть)